# Using a column of a join for argument the a function table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function

I am join a table with a postgresql function table.

```sql
    SELECT * FROM  tb_accounts a,
    (SELECT column1, column2 FROM ft_extra_data(a.id) ) e
```

And it is throwing me the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"
LINE 4:   ft_extra_data(a.id)  
                        ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 153
```

This would be an example of the table function (this example is to view the definition only):

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ft_extra_data(IN p_account_id bigint)
     RETURNS TABLE(
      column1 character varying, column2 character varying) AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT 'xxx' as column1, 'yyy' as column2;
    END;
    $BODY$
     LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
     COST 100
     ROWS 1000;
```

I've been doing some research and haven't found anything, is this impossible to do?

Code example:
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b218bbcaf8470f1f75f8d1e29d5207e6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access table `a` in the subquery (aka derived table) you must make the join lateral:

```
SELECT *
FROM  tb_accounts a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT column1, column2 FROM ft_extra_data(a.id) ) e;
```

---

Alternatively you can call put the function directly into the FROM clause without a derived table:

```
SELECT a.*, ft.column1, ft.column2
FROM  tb_accounts a
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ft_extra_data(a.id) as ft;
```

In that case the `lateral` is optional, as `ft_extra_data()` is defined to return a table.